# C programming splliting linked list into half

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I was having some problem when trying to split the linked list into half in C programming. Here is the code:

```
typedef struct _listnode {
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;         // You should not change the definition of ListNode

typedef struct _linkedlist {
    int size;
    ListNode *head;
} LinkedList;   

}
```

Comment: SplitLinkedList should not return -1 because it's void

Comment: Opps that was a mistake. Any ideas why it behaved that way?

Comment: Normally, this is done using two pointers to nodes. One pointer is advanced two nodes at a time, the other one node at a time. Then the two node at a time pointer reaches the end of the list, the one node at a time pointer is at the middle of the list.

Comment: @rcgldr I got confused. Would you mind to provide me with some code example which I can refer to?

Comment: @rcgldr Hello any ideas?

Comment: @IWasSoLost - I didn't notice you had a size member in the list structure, In that case, just advance a single pointer size/2 times to reach the middle of the list.

Comment: @rcgldr Can you check my edit portion? I not sure if I am doing correctly

Comment: @IWasSoLost - the edit portion looks correct, but since the list structure include a size, you won't need to use that method.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93879/discussion-between-i-was-so-lost-and-rcgldr).

Answer (score 1):

You don't say so, but I assume that when you split the list in two, you don't want to retain the original list. If that is so, you just need to find where to cut the links, for example:

```
head1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> NULL     head2 -> NULL

head1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL     head2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> NULL
```

Here, you must identify the new tail of the first loist, `tail`, in the example node 3. Set the head of the new list to `tail->next`, set `tail->next` to `NULL` and adjust the counts in your lists.

You don't need different branches for odd and even numbers in your code. If the list has an odd number of nodes, one list will have one node more than the other: `left = total / 2` will make the right list longer, `left = (total + 1) / 2` will make the left list longer. Just pick one and be done.

Comment: But I cannot change the structure of the linked list and list node. Any ideas how to fix this? I think it's because I am updating my head pointer? And for the just pick one and be done, what do you mean by that? Sorry I am confused

Comment: My answer doesn't require changing the structure of the list or node. By the way, you leak the memory of the removed nodes. My approach is simpler and faster.

Comment: But I thought you were using tail? Tail was part of the LinkedList structure right?

Comment: @MOegm Hello any ideas?

Comment: In my example, `tail` is just a local variable; it refers to the new tail, which is the node halfway through the list. You can find it with your `FindNode` function.

Comment: I see I see but how should I convert the diagram into code? I need a head start.

Comment: @IWasSoLost I think the issue you are having is understanding what a list is in memory and conceptualizing what this solution does. A node is nothing more than a struct of a given type in memory. It is only associated with a list by virtue of some *next* pointer pointing to it, and its *next* pointer pointing to something else. This solution does no more than change the `node3->next` to `NULL` and `head2->next` to the address of `node4`. This is the proper way to split a list.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have wrote out the code based on what MOehm said. But I not sure how to integrate with my front and back linkedlist. Any ideas?

Comment: @MOehm Excuse me, are you there?

Comment: @IWasSoLost it would help if you would edit your question (do not change the original question), but add your updated code below so we can see where you are. We are all happy to help, but are very bad mind-readers...